# print variables using console.log() with back ticks and dollar sign

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to print variables in an array using back ticks and dollar sign, but somehow it doesn't retrieve data from the array.

```js
    var buz = {
      fog: 'stack',
      snow: 'white'
    };

    for (var key in buz) {
      if (buz.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(`this is fog {$key} for sure. Value: {$buz[key]}`);
      } else {
        console.log(key); // toString or something else
      }
    }
```

this prints:

> this is fog {$key} for sure. Value: {$buz[key]}
>   this is fog {$key} for sure. Value: {$buz[key]}

How can I print:

> this is fog fog for sure. Value: stack
>     this is fog snow for sure. Value: white

?

Comment: ah thank you all so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `${expression}`. For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack',
  snow: 'white'
};

for (var key in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  console.log(`this is fog ${key} for sure. Value: ${buz[key]}`);
  } else {
    console.log(key); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `{$key}` to `${key}` and `{$buz[key]}` to `${buz[key]}` like following:

```
console.log(`this is fog ${key} for sure. Value: ${buz[key]}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

`` console.log(`this is fog ${key} for sure. Value: ${buz[key]}`); ``

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it wrong

it should be like this

`abc ${something}`